# Adding a duplicate number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently experiencing the following problem.

If you have a look at the below test case:

```
    declare @Count  int
    ,       @id     int =   777

    declare @table table
    (   id  int identity primary key
    ,   JCid    int
    ,   line    int
    ,   udf     float   )

    insert into @table (jcid,line,udf)
    values
    (777,1,1),
    (777,2,2.1),
    (777,3,2.2),
    (777,4,2),
    (777,5,3)


    select
        @Count  =   count(left(L.udf,1))
    from    @table L
    where   L.jcid  = @id
    group by left(L.udf,1)
    having count(left(L.udf,1))>1

    select  @Count
```

When I run this, I get the desired results of 3, however upon developing the below trigger, I can't get the count to work out correctly:

```
create trigger kv_trg_JobLineNumberUpdate_AW on _btblJCTxLines
after insert, update
as

declare @LineNum            float
,       @OldLine            float
,       @id                 int
,       @Count              int
,       @Err                nvarchar(500)

set @Err                =   '--------------------------';
set @Err                =   @Err    +   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
set @Err                =   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
set @Err                =   @Err    +   'You are not allowed to change this Line Number!';

select
    @LineNum    =   iLineID
,   @OldLine    =   isnull(ufJCTxCMLineNumber,0)
,   @id         =   iJCMasterID
from    inserted

select
    @Count  =   count(left(L.ufJCTxCMLineNumber,1))
from    _btblJCTxLines L
join    inserted i on left(L.ufJCTxCMLineNumber,1) = left(i.ufJCTxCMLineNumber,1)
where   L.iJCMasterID   = @id
group by left(L.ufJCTxCMLineNumber,1)
having count(left(L.ufJCTxCMLineNumber,1))>1

begin
    if  @OldLine    =   0
        begin
            if @Count   >=  2
                begin
                    update  _btblJCTxLines
                        set ufJCTxCMLineNumber      =   cast(@LineNum as varchar)+'.'+cast(@Count as varchar)
                    from    _btblJCTxLines  L
                    join    inserted on L.idJCTxLines   =   inserted.idJCTxLines
                end
            else
                begin
                    update  _btblJCTxLines
                        set ufJCTxCMLineNumber      =   @LineNum
                    from    _btblJCTxLines  L
                    join    inserted on L.idJCTxLines   =   inserted.idJCTxLines
                end
        end
    else
        begin
            select
                @OldLine        =   deleted.ufJCTxCMLineNumber
            ,   @LineNum        =   inserted.ufJCTxCMLineNumber
            from    inserted, deleted

                if  (@OldLine <> @LineNum)
                    begin
                        raiserror(@Err, 16, 1)
                        rollback tran
                        return;
                    end
        end
end
go
```

The ufJCTxCMLineNumber field is the duplicate number I'm looking for.

This triggers main purpose is to ensure that the ufJCTxCMLineNumber field never has duplicates.

What happens is, a user inserts a new line, when they add a new line above any current line, I want the ufJCTxCMLineNumber field to be updated to 3.1 depending on how many duplicates there is.

How would I go about getting the correct count?

Follow this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wc442ggzysumn7v/Sample%20Data.xlsx?dl=0) for Sample Data.

Comment: can you include some sample data and expected result for the table ?

Comment: How do I add the sample data? Tried to now, but not sure how.

Comment: I have the data in Excel format now...?

Comment: I've added a link to the body of the question for the sample data.

Comment: This trigger approach is totally wrong. You are working with 1 row of a table, instead of operation with tables. I did find an example like this in a tutorial once, and it was useless. You need to start over and work with inserted and deleted as tables, not as rows. Furthermore his syntax  **from  inserted, deleted** will give you a Cartesian result, it should ALWAYS be avoided.

Comment: Thanks for your comment t-clausen.dk, however, how would you suggest I approach it? You state that I need to start over, not sure how to be honest. I assume you understand what I intend to do, with that said, could you maybe give me some pointers?

Comment: Random [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26506440/updating-inserted-row-with-table-trigger/26508296#26508296) example I wrote earlier